# Does Angular Kendo supports server side pagination?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

AngularJS Kendo had default support for server side pagination. This can be enabled using flag serverPaging: true

Now we are migrating on Angular v6
I was exploring https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui, but could not find any reference for default support for server side pagination.

The pagination template constructs menu based on total records available. It cant be manipulated using total number records alone.

If anyone have implemented server side pagination using latest kendo-ui, please share the approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo UI for Angular data-bound components are agnostic of where their data comes from. For data operation purposes (including paging) [the Grid relies on emitting events that contain all necessary information for processing the data accordingly](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/automatic-operations/) - either on the client, or on the server.

The following examples demonstrate a Grid with server-side data operations:

[EXAMPLE 1](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations)

[EXAMPLE 2](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dataquery/mvc-integration/)

Comment: Thanks. I used same approach mentioned in above links and it worked for me.